# How to prove (∀a, b, c ∈ N) a < b ⇒ a < bc. using only the basic axioms of natural numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, alternative-proof, axioms, natural-numbers

(∀a, b, c ∈ N) a < b ⇒ a < bc
This is what I did :
Suppose that a, b, c ∈ N and a < b.
Since c ∈ N, we have c ≥ 1.
Thus, b = b · 1 ≤ b · c.
Therefore, a < b ≤ bc, which implies that a < bc.

I know what I did works but I want to prove it only assuming the axioms and nothing else. I don't want to use the fact that if c is a natural number then it is at least one since this is not an axiom but a proposition proved by the axioms. You guys have an idea how to do this? I've been stuck for more than 40 minutes.
These are the axioms that I am allowed to use :
N is closed under multiplication and addition.
0 is not an element of the naturals
For each a ∈ Z, a = 0 or a ∈ N or -a ∈ N
a < b implies  b -a ∈ N , a > b implies a -b ∈ N, a ≥ b implies a > b or a = b
I am allowed to use all the arithmetic in Z. thus Ican use the axioms and propositions in Z

Comment: That seems correct.  It's how I'd have done it.  You should include what axioms you are stating in your post if you want critique though.

Comment: In addition to the stated axioms, you also need to axiomatize or otherwise define inequalities.

Comment: @J.G. well for inequalities, i just need to negate the equality ? so, I just say that it is not the case that a < b , thus a ≥ b

Comment: But you still need to define at least one operator. For example, if you define $a\le b$ as $\exists m(b=a+m)$ and $a<b$ as $a\le b\land a\ne b$, you can prove the latter is equivalent to $\exists b(b=a+n+1)$. You then need $+$ to commute and associate when proving $a<b\le k\to a<k$.

Comment: Z is mentioned in the axioms. But what is Z? That is, what properties of Z are you allowed to use?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You are right, I forgot to mention this. Our teacher said we can use all the arithmetic in Z. The axioms and the propositions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given $b-a \in \mathbb{N}$ if $c =1$ we are done because $b=b \cdot 1$. Now because addition is closed in the natural number we also have $\sum_{k=1}^cb-a = cb -a \in \mathbb{N}$ and so $a < bc$.